# Multiple games with same rpg-classes base

Tags: c#, inheritance

*Please, if you find a better title, tell me because I really didn't know what to put in here!*

I like to guess how I could implement a game, and to be sure that my perception is working, I plan to develop small games. For instance, I plan to build a FFTA-like game, a FTL-like game, a tower-defense game, and so on. As a base, I created a bunch of rpg-classes (Warrior, Wizard, ...), and I want to use all of them in each of my futur game.

The only sure thing I know about what should be in common for every game is the stat system:

> - Strength
> - Constitution
> - Agility
> - Accuracy
> - Intelligence
> - Charisma
> - Luck

I will continue with what I plan to do, but I am not really sure about my choices:

```
namespace General
{
    public interface IStatsOwner
    {
        int Strength { get; }
        int Constitution { get; }
        int Agility { get; }
        int Accuracy { get; }
        int Intelligence { get; }
        int Charisma { get; }
        int Luck { get; }
    }

    public abstract class WarriorBase : IStatsOwner
    {
        public int Strength { get { return 5; } }
        public int Constitution { get { return 4; } }
        public int Agility { get { return 3; } }
        public int Accuracy { get { return 3; } }
        public int Intelligence { get { return 2; } }
        public int Charisma { get { return 3; } }
        public int Luck { get { return 1; } }
    }

    public abstract class WizardBase : IStatsOwner
    {
        public int Strength { get { return 2; } }
        public int Constitution { get { return 3; } }
        public int Agility { get { return 3; } }
        public int Accuracy { get { return 3; } }
        public int Intelligence { get { return 5; } }
        public int Charisma { get { return 4; } }
        public int Luck { get { return 1; } }
    }

    public interface IGame
    {
        Type WarriorType { get; }
        Type WizardType { get; }
    }
}
```

---

```
namespace FFTALike
{
    public interface IDamageable
    {
        void TakeDamages();
    }

    public class Warrior : General.WarriorBase, IDamageable
    { 
        public void TakeDamages() { Console.WriteLine($"Taking damages with CON={Constitution}"); }
    }

    public class Wizard : General.WizardBase, IDamageable
    {
        public void TakeDamages() { Console.WriteLine($"Taking damages with CON={Constitution}"); }
    }

    public Game : IGame
    {
        public Type WarriorType { get { return typeof(Warrior); } }
        public Type WizardType { get { return typeof(Wizard); } }
    }
}
```

---

```
namespace TowerDefense
{
    public interface ILocatable
    {
        Location Location { get; set; } // Location(int X, int Y)
    }

    public interface IShooter
    {
        void Shoot();
    }

    public class Warrior : WarriorBase, ILocatable, IShooter
    {
        public Location Location { get; set; }
        public void Shoot() { Console.WriteLine($"Shooting with STR={Strength}"); }
    }

    public class Wizard : WizardBase, ILocatable, IShooter
    {
        public Location Location { get; set; }
        public void Shoot() { Console.WriteLine($"Shooting with STR={Strength}"); }
    }

    public Game : IGame
    {
        public Type WarriorType { get { return typeof(Warrior); } }
        public Type WizardType { get { return typeof(Wizard); } }
    }
}
```

---

What I feel uncomfortable with is:

> - I don't enforce the fact that `IGame.WarriorType` inherits `WarriorBase`
> - I duplicate `TakeDamages()`, `Location { get; set; }` and `Shoot()` (I actually have 20 rpg-classes, so I *isocuplate* these implementations)

Please note that I want the final implementation to fit with `SOLID` principles, because I want these projects to be training projects.

Comment: This doesn't look like working code to me, and I don't see concrete game-specific requirements, so I'm afraid this is off-topic here. Either way, I think you're trying to generalize too early and too much, and you're doing too much at the type-level - a data-driven approach seems more suitable here.

Comment: About _public interface ILocatable // I don't know how to say :p_ - I find this is a perfect name for that interface! Exactly as it should be ;-)

Comment: This isn't doing anything yet. How would you use this? If you have no usage for it yet, you're too early with wanting to generalize it.

Comment: Regarding my note about 'doing too much at the type level', Eric Lippert wrote an interesting series about that: https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/

Answer (score 4):

I'm having trouble visualizing what your intention here is.

Let's talk about your code itself, then I'll move on to a slight redesign:

C# has a nice-new language feature called "Expression-Bodied members", basically, this:

```
public int Strength => 5;
```

That's equivalent, but much shorter than your version:

> ```
> public int Strength { get { return 5; } }
> ```

So, I would recommend moving to something like that, if you want to keep this design.

**But**, I would redesign this:

Everything has the same stats, right? They all need the stats, they just might have different values?

```
public class Stats
{
    public int Strength { get; }
    public int Constitution { get; }
    public int Agility { get; }
    public int Accuracy { get; }
    public int Intelligence { get; }
    public int Charisma { get; }
    public int Luck { get; }
}
```

So we're using another new language feature here: auto-implemented readonly properties. Basically: don't put code in the `get`, and these can only be set by the constructor. Of course, we *need* a constructor:

```
public Stats(int strength, int constitution, int agility, int accuracy, int intelligence, int charisma, int luck)
{
    Strength = strength;
    Constitution = constitution;
    Agility = agility;
    Accuracy = accuracy;
    Intelligence = intelligence;
    Charisma = charisma;
    Luck = luck;
}
```

Now, because everyone has their own specific stats, but they all follow the same structure, we use this class in the object:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public Stats Stats { get; }
    public Entity(Stats stats)
    {
        Stats = stats;
    }
}
```

So, because everybody is the same type of "Entity" with different attributes, we then move on to the `Warrior` / `Wizard` / etc.:

```
public abstract class Warrior : Entity
{
    public Warrior()
        : base(new Stats(5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1))
    { }
}

public abstract class Wizard : Entity
{
    public Wizard()
        : base(new Stats(2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 4, 1))
    { }
}
```

Now you can use the `ILocatable` etc. in the specific games, but the *basics* are all the same across-the-board. We build a more extracted model: the things that *have* to be there are, and are enforced.

With this part:

> ```
> public interface IGame
> {
>     Type WarriorType { get; }
>     Type WizardType { get; }
> }
> ```

We can do some trickery:

```
public abstract class Game<TWarrior, TWizard>
    where TWarrior : Warrior
    where TWizard : Wizard
{
    public Type WarriorType => typeof(TWarrior);
    public Type WizardType => typeof(TWizard);
}
```

Now, I don't know *why* you need the `WarriorType` or `WizardType`, you probably *don't* need them in this version, because we put those types on the `Game` class.

We obviously haven't handled the `TakeDamages` or `Shoot`, right? We need to find a way to deal with that on a game-by-game basis: enter **ECS** (entity-component-system).

We built the entities, they have stats (components), now we need "systems" to handle the components.

```
public class ActualWizard : Wizard { }
public class ActualWarrior : Warrior { }

public class ActualGame : Game<ActualWizard, ActualWarrior>
{
    public class ShootSystem
    {
        public static void Shoot(Entity source, Entity target)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Shooting with STR={source.Stats.Strength}");
        }
    }
}
```

So, now you would call `ShootSystem.Shoot(myWarrior, myWizard);`, which would be where you handle all of the logic to *actually shoot* the wizard with the warrior. This also means that *all entities* can use the same function, whatever they may be. (Paladin, etc.)

```
var myGame = new ActualGame();
var myWarrior = new ActualWarrior();
var myWizard = new ActualWizard();
myGame.ShootSystem.Shoot(myWarrior, myWizard);
```

You would add any stats *specific* to warriors to `ActualWarrior`, same with `ActualWizard`, but you don't put the *logic* there, you build a `System` for it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85231/discussion-on-answer-by-202-accepted-multiple-games-with-same-rpg-classes-base).